# Spring boot 3 : Secure RestController api's with keyclock ressource autorisations

Tags: spring-security, authorization, keycloak, user-permissions

I m working with spring boot 3 java 17 and keyclock 21.1.1.
I need to secure my rest api with keyclock ressource autorisation.
for that i added a key clock client

[image]

a client ressource
[image]

scopes
[image]

policy

[image]

and my permission

[image]

My RPT token

[image]

I'm using oauth2 dependancies

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Using @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('my_ressource', 'add')") is given me 403 forbiden

[image]

My Security config is

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    class SecurityConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource;
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    
            httpSecurity
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry.anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Configurer -> oauth2Configurer.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {
                        Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
                        Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get("roles");
                        var grantedAuthorities = roles.stream()
                                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt,grantedAuthorities , "");
                    })))
            ;
            return httpSecurity.build();
        }
        
    }
```

i need to adapte my security  config to use hasPermission.

Application log

```
    2023-09-12T17:39:18.444+01:00 DEBUG 1948 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.mypartner.tm.authentification.controller.UserBranchController.addKeyClock(); target is of class [com.mypartner.tm.authentification.controller.UserBranchController] 2023-09-12T17:39:18.452+01:00  WARN 1948 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.a.e.DenyAllPermissionEvaluator     : Denying user  permission 'add' on object my_ressource 2023-09-12T17:39:18.459+01:00 DEBUG 1948
    --- [nio-9000-exec-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.mypartner.tm.authentification.controller.UserBranchController.addKeyClock(); target is of class [com.mypartner.tm.authentification.controller.UserBranchController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@181c058b and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasPermission('my_ressource', 'add')] 2023-09-12T17:39:18.470+01:00 TRACE 1948 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@7e539329, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_default-roles-test, ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_test_role, ROLE_uma_authorization]] to access denied handler since access is denied
    
    org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:257)     at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:198)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)  at com.mypartner.tm.authentification.controller.UserBranchController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.addKeyClock(<generated>)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)  at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
```

PS :
`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('test_role')")`   is working for me.
I think that i shoud extract authorization ---> permissions : {ressource and scope } from jwt token

Comment: @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('my_ressource', 'add')")  not working for me it give 403 even if my user have the permission

Comment: please enbale debug logs and update your question with your full logs. You should always read them first before asking on stack overflow.

Comment: The problem here is he's using `hasPermission` without a `PermissionEvaluator` bean.

Comment: As a side note, you'd better declare the language of your code snippets to add syntax highlighting and also replace screenshots with snippets when possible (like JSON payload and Java code with expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasPermission` is evaluated by a `PermissionEvaluator`. The default (and only) implementation provided by Spring Security is `DenyAllPermissionEvaluator` which will ... deny all (all expressions with `hasPermission` result in 403).

You should provide with your own `PermissionEvaluator` bean reading from the `$.authorization.permissions` claim in your access tokens. Considering your `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('my_ressource', 'add')")` expression, maybe something like:

```java
@Component
public class KeycloakAuthorizationPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if(!(targetDomainObject instanceof String) || !(permission instanceof String)) {
            return false;
        }
        final var permissions = getAuthenticationPermissions(authentication);
        return Optional.ofNullable(permissions.get(targetDomainObject))
                .map(KeycloakAuthorizationPermission::scopes)
                .orElse(List.of())
                .contains(permission);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        final var permissions = getAuthenticationPermissions(authentication);
        // FIXME: implement permission evaluation there too if you use this method in your expressions
        return false;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Map<String, KeycloakAuthorizationPermission> getAuthenticationPermissions(Authentication authentication) {
        if(authentication instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
            final var authorization = (Map<String, Object>) jwtAuth.getToken().getClaims().getOrDefault("authorization", Map.of());
            final var permissions = (List<Map<String, Object>>) authorization.getOrDefault("permissions", Map.of());
            return permissions.stream().map(p -> {
                final var rsid = Optional.ofNullable(p.get("rsid")).orElse("").toString();
                final var rsname = Optional.ofNullable(p.get("rsname")).orElse("").toString();
                final var scopes = (List<String>) Optional.ofNullable(p.get("scopes")).orElse(List.of());
                return new KeycloakAuthorizationPermission(rsid, rsname, scopes);
            }).collect(Collectors.toMap(KeycloakAuthorizationPermission::rsname, p -> p));
        }
        return Map.of();
    }
    
    static final record KeycloakAuthorizationPermission(String rsid, String rsname, List<String> scopes) {}

}
```

Few notes:

- There is no specified limit to JWTs size, but it is provided as `Bearer` header and most servers set a limit of 8kB for headers. This means that **the number of entries in `$.authorization.permissions` is actually limited** (your system could stop working some day when you defined too many "resources" in Keycloak).
- Setting an empty string as username when building the `JwtAuthenticationToken` seems a pretty bad idea. Using `jwt.getClaim("preferred_username")` or `jwt.getClaim("sub")` would probably be much better.
- checking for a `add` permission on `@GetMapping` looks pretty suspicious: you shouldn't be using a `GET` when changing the sytem state (create => `POST`, update => `PUT` or `PATCH`, delete => `DELETE`). It is not just a matter of elegance and making you API coder-friendly: some security mechanisms rely on this (CSRF protection to start with).
- You should think twice before creating an adherence from Keycloak to the resources on your resource servers. To me, this is a code smell and would make a migration to another OpenID Provider a nightmare. When role based access control is not enough, I'd prefer one of the following:

  - if I am confident that the number of permissions will always fit in a `Bearer` header, I write a resource server for managing and exposing permissions. I then add a Keycloak "mapper" to call this resource server when building tokens and add the response as a private claim.
  - if there is a chance that the number of permissions becomes high, then I'd have nothing about it in tokens and the `PermissionEvaluator` implementation would read from a dedicated database. Of course, to get decent performance, I'd have to use some caching for DB requests, and if I had more than one resource server, I'd probably isolate permissions in a dedicated one (with some additional caching on REST calls to this `permissions` service).

In short, you're probably over complicating things and should think again about a way to solve your problem with good old Role Based Access Control (with just Keycloak "roles", not the "authorization" features), optionally augmented with evaluations on the resource itself. Something like:

```java
@PutMapping("/posts/{post-id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('moderator') || #post.authorName == authentication.name")
public ResponseEntity<Void> updatePost(@PathVariable("post-id") Post post, @RequestBody @Valid PostUpdateDto dto) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours notes
can you tell me more about making ressource for managing and exposing permissions
(i'm not familiar with spring security and keycloak)

Comment: About any OpenID Provider will have its own implementation for user roles, sometimes poorly named "groups" or "permissions" or whatever, when the aim is clearly to achieve **R**ole **B**ased **A**ccess **C**ontrol. Keycloak makes a distinction between "client" roles (defined only for a specific client) an "realm" roles (defined for all the client in that realm, but both are inteded to be used in RBAC.

Comment: Defining Roles in Keycloak is future proof: you'll always find a similar feature in another authorization server. For fancy access control rules, define it in your application code. Either as SpEL expression (or in a `PermissionEvaluator` if you want to use `hasPermission`)

Comment: You could find useful resources in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2)